# How does crawler multithreading work in this example?

Tags: go

I am trying solve task about parallel fetching URLs using cache to avoid duplicates.
I found correct solution and can understand it. I saw that correct answer contains channels and gorutines pushes URL in cache via chan. But why my simple code doesn't work properly?
I have no idea where is mistake.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type Fetcher interface {
    // Fetch returns the body of URL and
    // a slice of URLs found on that page.
    Fetch(url string) (body string, urls []string, err error)
}

var cache = struct {
    cache map[string]int
    mux sync.Mutex
}{cache: make(map[string]int)}

// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
    // TODO: Fetch URLs in parallel.
    // TODO: Don't fetch the same URL twice.
    // This implementation doesn't do either:

    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }
    cache.mux.Lock()
    cache.cache[url] = 1 //put url in cache
    cache.mux.Unlock()
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    for _, u := range urls {
        cache.mux.Lock()
        if _, ok := cache.cache[u]; !ok { //check if url already in cache
            cache.mux.Unlock()
            go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher)
        } else {
            cache.mux.Unlock()
        }
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    Crawl("http://golang.org/", 4, fetcher)
}

// fakeFetcher is Fetcher that returns canned results.
type fakeFetcher map[string]*fakeResult

type fakeResult struct {
    body string
    urls []string
}

func (f fakeFetcher) Fetch(url string) (string, []string, error) {
    if res, ok := f[url]; ok {
        return res.body, res.urls, nil
    }
    return "", nil, fmt.Errorf("not found: %s", url)
}

// fetcher is a populated fakeFetcher.
var fetcher = fakeFetcher{
    "http://golang.org/": &fakeResult{
        "The Go Programming Language",
        []string{
            "http://golang.org/pkg/",
            "http://golang.org/cmd/",
        },
    },
    "http://golang.org/pkg/": &fakeResult{
        "Packages",
        []string{
            "http://golang.org/",
            "http://golang.org/cmd/",
            "http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/",
            "http://golang.org/pkg/os/",
        },
    },
    "http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/": &fakeResult{
        "Package fmt",
        []string{
            "http://golang.org/",
            "http://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
    "http://golang.org/pkg/os/": &fakeResult{
        "Package os",
        []string{
            "http://golang.org/",
            "http://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
}
```

UPD:
Result of execution:

```
found: http://golang.org/ "The Go Programming Language"

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I feel like no recursion when i launch goroutine. But if make breakpoint on line which checks if URL in cahce, i got this:

```
found: http://golang.org/ "The Go Programming Language"
found: http://golang.org/pkg/ "Packages"

Debugger finished with exit code 0
```

so that means recursion works, but something gones wrong, some race i guess?
More interesting thing happens when add second breakpoint on line which runes routine:

```
found: http://golang.org/ "The Go Programming Language"
found: http://golang.org/pkg/ "Packages"
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex(0x58843c, 0x0, 0x1)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:71 +0x47
sync.(*Mutex).lockSlow(0x588438)
        /usr/local/go/src/sync/mutex.go:138 +0x295
sync.(*Mutex).Lock(0x588438)
        /usr/local/go/src/sync/mutex.go:81 +0x58
main.Crawl(0x4e9cf9, 0x12, 0x4, 0x4f7700, 0xc00008c180)
        /root/go/src/crwaler/main.go:38 +0x46c
main.main()
        /root/go/src/crwaler/main.go:48 +0x57

goroutine 18 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex(0x58843c, 0x0, 0x1)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:71 +0x47
sync.(*Mutex).lockSlow(0x588438)
        /usr/local/go/src/sync/mutex.go:138 +0x295
sync.(*Mutex).Lock(0x588438)
        /usr/local/go/src/sync/mutex.go:81 +0x58
main.Crawl(0x4ea989, 0x16, 0x3, 0x4f7700, 0xc00008c180)
        /root/go/src/crwaler/main.go:38 +0x46c
created by main.Crawl
        /root/go/src/crwaler/main.go:41 +0x563

Debugger finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Hi, please try to provide more details about what you obtain launching the program and why is not ok. If you got an error, please provide the text in your post.

Comment: One issue I saw in your code is when you use _cache.mux.Lock()_ as you _Unlock()_ only inside the if, so one goroutine that found the url in cache is going to lock everyone else.

Comment: Another issue is that you should lock the cache when you write to it, now you do only when you read.

Comment: @MarioSantini you right! I added else condition to unlock mutex and result doesn't change. (Also saw about writing then and fixed). But when i debugging and making pauses between speps it works almost fine and found one more url. There must be another issue... I starting believe that blocking must be little complicated to work fine and avoid deadlocks. So should i use channels to manage locks or there is easier way?

Comment: I think channels will make no difference as they just aim to synchronize goroutine but not to access resources in concurrency, as it is your cache.

Comment: to check for race condition you should use the _-race_ option on _go build_. It should highlight some issues.

Comment: You're also not waiting for any `go Crawl` calls to return, so you could get any number of results

Comment: @JimB if i right understood, the return is happening when counter of depth==0. Or there is some specific procedure in golang concurrency?

Comment: You have no synchronization between the main goroutine and the Crawl goroutines, so main will exit before all your goroutines complete. I would just continue with the tutorials before you go off into the weeds.

Comment: You can see what @JimB is telling you just launching the _Crawl()_ in the main as a goroutine. The program will exit immidiately without completing a fetch. Now it is keep running by the for loop.

Comment: @MarioSantini i also deleted "go Crawl" so because of it code started works... When i idded -race option it also works with goroutines and sometimes returns two or one "not found: http://golang.org/cmd/". Yep, there is race and i guess i should synchronize threads to avoid it.
As marked JimB i can wait for return.
Thank everyone, gone to read the docs ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `main()` does not block until all `go Crawl()` invocations are finished, therefor exiting. You could either use a `sync.WaitGroup` or a channel to synchronize program ending with the completion of all goroutines.

I also see a problem with the variable `u` used within the goroutine; by the time the goroutine is executed the value of `u` might or might not have been changed by the range-loop.

The end of `Crawl` could look like this to resolve both issues;

```golang
wg := sync.WaitGroup{}

fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
for _, u := range urls {
    cache.mux.Lock()
    if _, ok := cache.cache[u]; !ok { //check if url already in cache
        cache.mux.Unlock()
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(url string) {
            Crawl(url, depth-1, fetcher)
            wg.Done()
        }(u)
    } else {
        cache.mux.Unlock()
    }
}

// Block until all goroutines are done
wg.Wait()

return
```